# Make sure a class does not inherit from two interfaces

Tags: c++, c++14

I have this problem. There is a framework that is developed and used by us. We have a few interfaces that the user of this framework needs to implement. I want to make sure that two of these interfaces can never be implemented on the same class. here is an example

```
class A{
  void a() = 0;
};
class B{
  void b() = 0;
};

class C: public A, public B { // This should give error
};
class D: public A{ // OK
};
```

So far I thought maybe I can use `static_assert` and `std::is_convertible` but I can't put my hands on how to do it.

Edit:
I don't know who is going to write the derived classes so I want to have it in the base interfaces if possible. Basically assume that I don't have access to derived classes because they are not in our code base.

Thanks.

Comment: "I want to make sure that two of these interfaces can never be implemented on the same class." If a user is able to do it, it is functional valid, effective and clear in design, there is no reason to tease a user with broken interface conventions. Looks you want to write a text adventure!

Comment: This is not my design and I cant change it. I see in the code that the original author does dynamic casting and gives runtime error which is worst. I want to see if I can make it at least into a compile time error

Comment: Dynamic cast to what? You did not want to tell me that he tries to cast to all of the broken interface classes, count the number and throws an error if found more than once? No! :-) Who pays for improving the badness of an interface?

Comment: You see the type of headache I am experiencing . I would love to fix this in a good way but it is not a decision I can make at the moment as the code is hooked into many places. Also I have not told you guys half of it.

Comment: For me it feels that you don't (only) have a technical issue. It may be worth to go to your boss, ask for better team education, create better code guidelines, take part of beneficial code reviews, don't follow academic rules ( multiple inheritance is eval idiom ) and invest in software capital! "Improving" bad ideas will not help I believe.

Comment: That I already am doing because whenever I look at this it hurts me. I am more curiouse to see if some genius here can bend the rules. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: You are owner of class A and B and able to modify that code?

Comment: This can't be done. The base class knows noting of the classes derived from it.

Comment: Yes I am the owner of classes A and B @Klaus

Answer (score 2):

Write own trait like this:

```cpp
template<typename Derived, typename... BaseCandidates>
struct has_no_base;

template<typename Derived>
struct has_no_base<Derived>
    : std::true_type { };

template<typename Derived, typename BaseFirst, typename... BasesRest>
struct has_no_base<Derived, BaseFirst, BasesRest...>
    : std::conditional_t<
        std::is_base_of<BaseFirst, Derived>,
        std::true_type,
        has_no_base<Derived, BasesRest...>
      > { };

template<typename Derived, typename... PossibleBases>
struct has_only_one_base;

template<typename Derived>
struct has_only_one_base<Derived>
    : std::false_type { };

template<typename Derived, typename Base>
struct has_only_one_base<Derived, Base>
    : std::conditional_t<
        std::is_base_of_v<Base, Derived>,
        std::true_type,
        std::false_type
      > { };

template<typename Derived, typename BaseFirst, typename... BasesRest>
struct has_only_one_base<Derived, BaseFirst, BasesRest...>
    : std::conditional_t<
        std::is_base_of_v<BaseFirst, Derived>,
        has_no_base<Derived, BasesRest...>,
        has_only_one_base<Derived, BasesRest...>
      > { };
```

And use it like that:

```cpp
class MyClass : public A, public B
{
    static_assert(has_only_one_base<MyClass, A, B>::value, "Error");
};
```

Moreover, as far as you are a developer of this framework, you can provide some check trait:

```cpp
template<typename Type>
using is_valid_class = has_only_one_base<Type, IFirst, ISecond, ... ILast>;
```

And use it:

```cpp
class MyClass : public A, public B
{
    static_assert(is_valid_class<MyClass>::value, "Error");
};
```

Comment: OP asks how he can guarantee that nobody inherits from two interfaces. If the user how "abuses" the interface, why this user should do the check himself. And in your case, I can write all and everything in the assert clause. I can't see what this one helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, since this is a framework assume that I dont have access to the derived class. I only know the interfaces in the framework. Can I put these asserts somewhere in the interfaces?

Comment: @Ashkan: Exactly! This "solution" is none as it needs the user itself to say: I do it wrong. Helps for nothing :-)

Comment: @Klaus I think there's no such way to guarantee the absence of multi-interface inheritance. The only way is to assume verbal contract either to inherit only one interface or to put `is_valid_class` assertion to raise compile-time error when user's class inherits 2 or more interfaces

Comment: Maybe? But if your answer did not answer OPs question, why it is still present. In my eyes your code helps for nothing as in the end the user has to write his own check to check himself to do the wrong thing. Sorry, can you help me to understand what your answer is good for? Wondering people upvote this answer... :-)

Comment: @Ashkan you can't write something, that you can put to your interfaces to check your contract. (At least without some "black magic" with compiler intrinsics).